# Cant get hubs from BIM 360 by using Forge Data Management API

Tags: autodesk, forge, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to get all my hubs from a360 and BIM360.
I already have access to my BIM 360 Account and “Apps & Integrations” is visible to me. Also added integration with Forge application.

I have sent a request with my 3-Legged Token:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer wIHYfJt80v2AvkTSUZxxxxxxxxxx" "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs"
```

But responce contains only a360 hubs and error message

```
"warnings": [
      {
        "Id": null,
        "HttpStatusCode": "403",
        "ErrorCode": "BIM360DM_ERROR",
        "Title": null,
        "Detail": "Failed to get the hubs.",
        "AboutLink": null,
        "meta": []
      }
```

Could you please explain me what could be wrong? Maybe you had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2/23/2017 - Update. 
You can access BIM 360 Docs hubs now if you have an enterprise account. For more information, please refer to this post:

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-enterprise-activating-api-access-to-docs/

11/8/2016 - original. 
Right now, the scope of BIM 360 API is limitted to Account level.
Also, it uses 2-legged.

For further explanations, please refer to these page:

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/bim-360-api-on-forge/

https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/bim-360-account-level-api-available-as-preview-beta/

Hope to have it exposed near future.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can I access hubs by using Forge DM? Or is it only for closed beta functionality?

Comment: As of today, you cannot access data in Docs using DM API.  You can access account level data of the given hub using BIM 360 API.  We are hoping to have DM access to Docs near future.

Comment: But in your video on youtube [https://youtu.be/52xkO85iLnw?t=16m29s](https://youtu.be/52xkO85iLnw?t=16m29s) I can see request for getting hubs and other useful requests. Can I get an access to this functionality?

Comment: During the DevCon, I showed it using internal server as a preview of what's coming.  It's taking longer than expected, feels like, I know.  But it is coming. Feel free to check with me @ mikako.harada@autodesk.com maybe in a month or so.  We may have a bit more accurate expected date by that time.  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, but the problem is presenting itself now.

Our application has been connected to BIM 360 Docs, however a request to get all hubs from Forge will not return this BIM 360 Docs hub.

We've verified that the administrator has activated the app in the Administrative tool.

What else should be checked?